# Vue.js Как рендерить страницу? или как правильно подключить скрипты

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, render

Здравствуйте!
Решил изучать `vue.js`. Не знаю как бы отрендерить страницу, в доках непонятно. Вот и интересует как правильно рендерить страницу от сервера на ноде. Сейчас все настроено так:

Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое hello.html:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если запустить сервак и обратиться к `/hello`, то рендерится пустая страница.

Но если просто открыть страницу, то сразу рендерится и надпись `Hello Vue!`.

Comment: да, html. Я рендерил статические html файлы, теперь же возможно какой нибудь другой движок нужен, не знаю)

Comment: не [SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/) ли случаем вас интересует?

Comment: ну, да, интересует SSR и как с ним работать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для понимания и использования техники SSR в Vue.js, есть прекрасный сайт https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/ и готовое решение https://ru.nuxtjs.org

Для "рендера" html шаблонизаторы не нужны, эти страницы можно открывать напрямую из "статичной" директории `express`.

```
...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
...
```

если в директории public есть файлы `index.html`, `app.html`, то можно получить к ним доступ по url: `/`, `/index.html`, `app.html`.

Шаблонизаторы - это для отрисовки и манипуляции данными, логики отображения, использования макетов и включений и т.д.

> html также можно компоновать и отсылать через `res.send(...)` http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#res.send

Comment: Да, спасибо, я это знаю) Все же решил что SSR мне не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Установите двигатель по умолчанию как "hbs" вместо "html"

//Установка «view», как показано ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

//Рендеринг файла, как показано ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но я не использую Handlebars)

Comment: @FreeRiderTvolex Правильно он сказал. `'view engine', 'hbs'`. Вы в коде шаблона используете его, а в "главном файле" у вас написана какая-то `'html'`.

Comment: Этот синтаксис - `{{ message }}` - ханделбарский.